# How can I maintain the socket id in node js(express)?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am developing new website using socket, and my goal is to make real-time chatting service. I am using socket to make real-time service, but there is two problems.

1. There is a login service, so I want to link the logged-in account with the socket id to determine each user only by socket id and automatically output the username when chatting. However, socket id is having difficulty in this process because it keeps changing every time you move the page.
2. When chatting, I want to enter a room code to enable chatting inside each room using socket room join, but when redirecting to the chat room after socket room join, the socket id changes again, and the client uses a socket id that is not joined. How to maintain the socket id during redirect

below is my code.

```
// server code
exports.ChatRoomSocket = (server) => {
  const io = socketio(server);
  const chatsocket = io.of('/chat');

  let rooms = {};

  function generateRoomCode() {
    let roomCode;
    do {
        roomCode = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString();
    } while (rooms[roomCode]);
    return roomCode;
  }

  chatsocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("User Connected : ", socket.id);

    socket.on("Create Room", (data) => {
      const hostName = data.hostname;
      let roomcode = generateRoomCode();

      rooms[roomcode] = {
        host: socket.id, 
        players: [socket.id], 
        playerName: [hostName], 
        numOfPlayer: 1,
      };

      socket.join(roomcode);

      socket.emit('Room Created',
        {roomcode, 
        socketID: socket.id,
        playerNames: rooms[roomcode].playerName
      });

      console.log('room Created!:', roomcode);
      console.log('All existing room codes:', Object.keys(rooms).join(', '));

    }) 

    socket.on("Join Room", (data) => {
      var roomcode = data.roomcode;

      if (rooms[roomcode]) {
        // console.log("joined");
        rooms[roomcode].numOfPlayer += 1;
        rooms[roomcode].playerName.push(data.playername);
        rooms[roomcode].players.push(socket.id);

        socket.join(roomcode);

        console.log(rooms[roomcode]);
        
        chatsocket.in(roomcode).emit('Room Joined', {
          roomcode,
          socketID: socket.id,
          playerNames: rooms[roomcode].playerName
        })

      } else {
        chatsocket.to(socket.id).emit('Error', {error: "Roomcode not found!!"});
      }
    })
    socket.on("Joining", (data) => {
      console.log(data, data.roomcode);
      chatsocket.in(data.roomcode).emit("New User", data);
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', async () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
  });
};
```

```
var socket = io("/chat", {
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionDelay: 1000,
  reconnectionAttempts: 5,
  forceNew: false
});

function joinRoom(roomcode) {
  socket.emit('Join Room', {playername: 'dd', roomcode: roomcode});

  socket.on('Room Joined', (data) => {
    if (roomcode === data.roomcode) {
      const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
      window.location.replace(currentPath + '/' + roomcode);
      socket.emit("Joining", {user: socket.id, roomcode: roomcode});
    } else {
      alert('Something Wrong!! Try again');
    }
  })
}

function createRoom(hostname) {
  socket.emit('Create Room', {'hostname': hostname});

  socket.on('Room Created', (data) => {
    console.log('Room created with code: ', data.roomcode);
    console.log('Your player ID: ', data.socketID);

    const currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    window.location.replace(currentPath + '/' + data.roomcode);
    socket.emit("Joining", {'user': socket.id, 'roomcode': roomcode});
    alert("wow!!!");
  });
}

socket.on("Error", (err) => {{
  alert(err.error);
}})
```

Whenever I redirected, I tried to update the session and socket id to dictionary. But I think this way is too inefficient.. Help me :(